# Customer is not able to log into their account with Multi-website shop in Magento

Tags: magento

I have created three websites in magento 1.9.1.0 using `rwd` theme. With the main website customer could successfully log in. But when customer tries to log in with the other two websites, will be redirected to login page without showing any error.

We have checked the form key and it exists in both websites. There is no JavaScript error and no external extension is installed.

Comment: I guess the user must be saved to all websites, not just one website (with N storeviews). Are you mixing up the keywords perhaps?

Comment: I have found the issue the cookie path was set to "/" for other two websites. I have removed the cookie path and then its working fine.